# Get_next_line : Abort when BUFFER_SIZE between 8 and 15 on Mac

Tags: c, macos, abort

I am currently completing my "Get_next_line" project. It is a function that reads a file and allows you to read a line ending with a newline character from a file descriptor. When you call the function again on the same file, it grabs the next line. This project deals with memory allocation and when to free and allocate memory to prevent leaks. The value `(-1)` is returned if an error occurred, `(0)` is returned if the file is finished reading, and `(1)` is returned if a line is read.

However, while testing my final code I encounter an abort when `BUFFER_SIZE` is between 8 and 15. This error only appears on Mac. Does anyone have an idea of what might be the issue?

Compile with :

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -D BUFFER_SIZE=32 get_next_line.c get_next_line_utils.c
```

The `get_next_line()` function and some support code;

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

int ft_backslash(const char *s)
{
    int i;

    i = -1;
    while (s[++i])
        if (s[i] == '\n')
            return (1);
    if (s[i] == '\n')
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

int ft_read_buffer(int fd, char *buf)
{
    int     ret;

    ret = 0;
    ret = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (ret < 0)
        return (-1);
    buf[ret] = '\0';
    return (ret);
}

char    *ft_treat_save(char *save, char *buf)
{
    char    *tmp;

    if (save == NULL)
        save = ft_strdup(buf);
    else
    {
        tmp = ft_strdup(save);
        free (save);
        save = ft_strjoin(tmp, buf);
        free (tmp);
    }
    return (save);
}

char    *ft_treat_tmp(char *save)
{
    char    *tmp;

    tmp = ft_strdup(save);
    free (save);
    return (tmp);
}

int get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
{
    int         ret;
    char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char        *tmp;
    static char *save;

    ret = 1;
    if (fd < 0 || fd > 255 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || line == NULL)
        return (-1);
    *line = NULL;
    tmp = NULL;
    while (ret > 0)
    {
        if ((ret = ft_read_buffer(fd, buf)) < 0)
            return (-1);
        save = ft_treat_save(save, buf);
        if (ft_backslash(save) == 1)
        {
            tmp = ft_treat_tmp(save);
            *line = ft_strcut_front(tmp);
            save = ft_strcut_back(tmp);
            return (1);
        }
    }
    tmp = ft_treat_tmp(save);
    save = NULL;
    *line = ft_strdup(tmp);
    free (tmp);
    return (0);
}
```

Other support code:

```
size_t  ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    if (str)
        while (str[i])
            i++;
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strdup(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    char    *dst;

    dst = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((ft_strlen(str) + 1)));
    if (!(dst))
    {
        free (dst);
        return (NULL);
    }
    i = -1;
    while (str[++i])
        dst[i] = str[i];
    dst[i] = '\0';
    return (dst);
}

char    *ft_strjoin(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *join;

    i = -1;
    j = 0;
    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (NULL);
    join = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 2));
    if (!(join))
        return (NULL);
    if (BUFFER_SIZE == 1)
        while (s1[++i + 1] != '\0')
            join[i] = s1[i];
    else
        while (s1[++i] != '\0')
            join[i] = s1[i];
    while (s2[j])
        join[i++] = s2[j++];
    join[i] = '\0';
    return (join);
}

char    *ft_strcut_front(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    char    *front;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    front = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1));
    if (!(front))
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n')
    {
        front[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    front[i] = '\0';
    return (front);
}

char    *ft_strcut_back(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *back;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    i++;
    back = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((ft_strlen(str) - i) + 1));
    if (!(back))
        return (NULL);
    j = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
        back[j++] = str[i++];
    back[j] = '\0';
    free (str);
    return (back);
}
```

The `main()` function:

```
int          main(void)
{
    int fd, ret, line_count;
    char *line;

    line_count = 1;
    ret = 0;
    line = NULL;
    fd = open("baudelaire.txt", O_RDONLY);
    while ((ret = get_next_line(fd, &line)) > 0)
    {
        printf(" \n [ Return: %d ] | A line has been read #%d => |%s|\n", ret, line_count, line);
        line_count++;
    }
    printf(" \n [ Return: %d ] A line has been read #%d: |%s\n", ret, line_count++, line);
    printf("\n");
    if (ret == -1)
        printf("-----------\n An error happened\n");
    else if (ret == 0)
    {
        printf("-----------\n EOF has been reached\n");
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Instead of screen copy, a real extract of you code would be easier to copy/past/run. Use ``` (triple back quote) around your code.

Comment: Are you aware that it is not possible to copy your picturs into a text editor and try to run it? Do you expect anyone to re-type everything? If not, then please edit your question to includ the code. And reduce the amount of code to a minimum that still compiles and reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry, here you go, you can now copy and past

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I forgot to add + 1 to my buf size... stupid error ! Thank you